# Find if a inner dict contains a value in a specific interval

Tags: python, dictionary

I hope you coding gurus can help me yet again.

I have a dict, in which i have an inner dict with information. Here is an exampel:

```
    {
     'John': {'age': 27,'height': 181,'children': 2},
     'Jack': {'age': 33,'height': 203,'children': 1},
     'Carl': {'age': 52,'height': 162,'children': 3}
    }
```

I then have some criteria in in a tuple with inner tuples, like this:

```
    (('age', 30, 60), ('height', 180, 220))
```

And in the inner tuples, the first value is the thing to check for, and then the minimum and maximum in the interval. What i want to return, is a list over the persons who makes ALL criteria, so in the example above, we should just have:

```
    ['Jack']
```

But how can i do this in a smart and good way? I was planing to go through all the persons, and for each person then check if the person fulfilled the criteria. I tried the following:

```
    def findPerson(persons, criteria):
        for p in persons:
            for tuble in criteria:
```

But this seems to lead nowhere, as p seems to be just the persons name, and not the entire entry, so I'm back to square one. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use list comprehension and [`all`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) function, like this

```
d = {
     'John': {'age': 27,'height': 181,'children': 2},
     'Jack': {'age': 33,'height': 203,'children': 1},
     'Carl': {'age': 52,'height': 162,'children': 3}
    }
rules = (('age', 30, 60), ('height', 180, 220))
print [k for k, v in d.items() if all(s <= v[key] <= e for key, s, e in rules)]
```

**Output**

```
['Jack']
```

The same list comprehension code, can be written like this

```
result = []
for k, v in d.items():
    for key, start, end in rules:
        if not (start <= v[key] <= end): break
    else:
        result.append(k)
print result
```

Comment: very concise, but maybe not clear for someone less familiar with python (such as the poster)

Comment: I forgot about tuple unpacking on the rules.  You don't need the parens there either.

Comment: @wim Yup. Saving two more bytes :) Thanks :)

Comment: Great answer, and as clear as can be. But, when using your second (more explisit) solution, it doesnt seem to return those who fits all criteria, but just one of them?

Comment: @Nick Could you please provide test data for that case?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> d = {
...      'John': {'age': 27,'height': 181,'children': 2},
...      'Jack': {'age': 33,'height': 203,'children': 1},
...      'Carl': {'age': 52,'height': 162,'children': 3}
...     }
>>> conds = (('age', 30, 60), ('height', 180, 220))
>>> [k for (k,v) in d.items() if all(cond[1] <= v[cond[0]] <= cond[2] for cond in conds)]
['Jack']
```

Answer (score 0):

this should help you on your way:

```
def findPerson(persons, criteria):
    for person,properties in persons.items():
        for tuble in criteria:
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for that:

```
for p in persons:
    passes = True
    for c in criteria:
        if persons[p][c[0]] < c[1] or persons[p][c[0]] < c[2]:
            passes = False
    if passes:
        print p
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import partial
def dict_filter(values, obj):
    for key, val1, val2 in values:
        value = obj[1].get(key)
        if value is None or (value <= val1 or value >= val2):
            break
    else: 
        return True


d = {
    'John': {'age': 27,'height': 181,'children': 2}, 
    'Jack': {'age': 33,'height': 203,'children': 1},
    'Carl': {'age': 52,'height': 162,'children': 3}
}

conds = (('age', 30, 60), ('height', 180, 220))
persons = filter(partial(dict_filter, conds), d.iteritems())
```